# how to select a word in list by its index in python

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing

```
import random
print('Welcome to the Guess-The-Word Game.')
print('Password is one of the words:')

wordList = ['AETHER', 'BADGED', 'BALDER', 'BANDED', 'BANTER', 'BARBER', 'BASHER', 'BATHED']

for index,word in enumerate(wordList):
print(index , '-', word)

password =(random.choice(wordList))

guess = None
counter = 0
while guess !=  password:
    guess = input('enter your guess:')
    counter = counter + 1

    if counter ==4:
    print('Game over')

    elif guess == password:
    print(password, ' is correct')

    else:
    print('wrong guess try again')
```

In the code the user input the guess word directly. Is there any way the user can enter the guess as index of the word instead of completely typing the complete word.

Comment: Yes, there is. Do you have a real question?

Comment: Here is documentation for Python 3.x data structures https://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: i am new to python. can you tell how can it be achieved??

Comment: Just use ``my_list_variable[item_index]``.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Hope you are trying for this:

```
import random
print('Welcome to the Guess-The-Word Game.')
print('Password is one of the words:')

wordList = ['AETHER', 'BADGED', 'BALDER', 'BANDED', 'BANTER', 'BARBER', 'BASHER', 'BATHED']

status_flag = False
guess = None
counter = 0
password =(random.choice(wordList))
word_index = wordList.index(password)
max_index = len(wordList)-1

while guess !=  password:
    guess = input('Enter your guess:[0 -'+str(max_index)+']')
    if guess > max_index:
        print ('Wrong input: Enter your guess:[0 -'+str(max_index)+']')
        continue

    counter = counter + 1
    if counter ==4:
        print('Game over')
        status_flag = True

    elif guess == word_index:
        print(str(password)+' is correct')
        status_flag = True

    else:
        print('Wrong guess try again')

    if status_flag:
        break
```